# Radius of circle tangent to six tangent parabolas

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

> Six congruent copies of the parabola $y = x^2$ are arranged in the plane so that each vertex is tangent to a circle, and each parabola is tangent to its two neighbors. Find the radius of the circle.
> [image]

I'm honestly not sure how to start this problem. The vertices of the parabolas are spaced $60^\circ$ apart on the circumference of the circle, and the points where two parabolas are tangent are also spaced $60^\circ$ apart, $30^\circ$ from a vertex. But I'm not sure how this is useful.

I also know that the focus and directrix of each parabola are the same distance from the vertex, and the directrixes (is that the plural?) intersect $60^\circ$ apart, $30^\circ$ from a vertex. But again, I don't know how useful that is.

Normally on problems like these I'd try to draw a radius and form some right triangles but I really don't see how I can do that here.

TIA!

Comment: Hint:Let the radius be $r$ then we have to find $r$ such that the pair of tangents to $y=x^2$  from the point$(-r,0)$ make  an angle of $60^{\circ}$ which is easy coordinate geometry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to look at a single parabola of the form $y = x^2 + r$, and determine $r$ such that the parabola is tangent to the lines $$y = \pm \sqrt{3} x.$$  This $r$ will be the radius of the inscribed circle.  See the following figure, which only shows the top and bottom parabolas, but adds the lines:

[image]

To this end, we compute the derivative $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$$ and equate it to $\pm \sqrt{3}$ to obtain $$x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$  These are the $x$-values at which the parabola is tangent.  So we require $$(\pm \sqrt{3}/2)^2 + r = \pm \sqrt{3}(\pm \sqrt{3}/2) = 3/2,$$ hence $$r = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: You may be interested by the solution I just gave using complex numbers geometry.

Answer (score 3):

Geometrically, consider a parabola with focus $F$, vertex $V$, and directrix through $D$ (so that $\overline{TF}\cong\overline{TT'}$, where $T'$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $T$ to the directrix). We require $T$ make $\angle TKF=30^\circ$, where $K$ is the center of the ostensible circle.

[image]

The Reflection Property tells us that $\overline{TK}$ bisects $\angle FTT'$, and we deduce that $\triangle FTT'$ is equilateral, and thus also is $\triangle FKT'$. Consequently, the directrix bisects $\overline{FK}$. Since $V$ bisects $\overline{FD}$, we conclude that $|KV| = 3|FV|$.

For the specific case of the parabola defined by $y=1x^2=\dfrac{1}{4\,|FV|}x^2$, we have $|FV|=1/4$, so that $|KV|=3/4$.

---

Inspired by [@JeanMarie's generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4056181/409), here's a revised argument:

[image]

For arbitrary $\theta:=\angle FKT$, and vertex-to-focus distance $a$, a little angle-chasing and the Reflection Property ultimately yield $\triangle FVM\sim\triangle MVK$, so that
$$|KV|=a\cot^2\theta$$
In the context of fitting $n$ tangent $y=x^2$ parabolas together about $K$, we have $\theta=\frac{\pi}{n}$ and $a=\frac14$, so that this agrees with @JeanMarie's result. $\square$

Comment: I have written a generalization of the given issue with any number of parabolas.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Indeed! ... In my figure, taking $\theta:=\angle FKT$ to be arbitrary, a little angle chasing shows that $\square KFTT'$ is a rhombus (but with a non-congruent diagonal $\overline{FT'}$), and that $\angle FT'D=\theta$. Then $$|DF|=|FT'|\sin\theta=2|KF|\sin^2\theta$$ so that $$\frac{|KV|}{|VF|}=\frac{|KF|-\frac12|DF|}{\frac12|DF|}=\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\quad\to\quad |KV|=|VF|\cot^2\theta=\frac14\cot^2\theta$$ and we agree. :)

Comment: Thank you for giving a "geometric flavor" to this $\dfrac14 \operatorname{cot}^2\theta$...

Comment: @JeanMarie: Happy to help. :) ... BTW: Here's a more-direct geometric calculation: Taking $M$ the midpoint of $\overline{FT'}$ (and noting that $\overline{MV}$, as a midpoint segment of $\triangle FT'D$, is parallel to $\overline{T'D}$) we have $$|FV|=|MV|\tan\theta=|KV|\tan^2\theta$$

Comment: Indeed much more direct.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be treated using complex numbers geometry.

Indeed, if we take the initial parabola with a horizontal axis of symmetry, it can be written as the locus of points

$$z=t^2+it+r, \ \  t \in \mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$

(with unknown $r$). The symmetry with respect to abscissas axis being obtained by changing $t$ into $-t$.

Therefore, as rotation by $\pi/3$ is obtained by

$$z \to \omega z, \ \ \text{with} \ \ \omega:=e^{i\pi/3}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag{2}$$

we can express the tangency of the initial parabola with its rotated version by saying that the following equation has a double root:

$$\omega(t^2+it+r)=(t^2\color{red}{-}it+r)\tag{3}$$

This equation can be written :

$$(\omega-1)t^2+i(\omega+1)t+(\omega-1)r=0\tag{4}$$

The double root condition is equivalent to nullify the discriminant of (4):

$$\Delta=-(\omega+1)^2-4(\omega-1)^2r=0$$

giving:

$$r=-\dfrac14\left(\dfrac{\omega+1}{\omega-1}\right)^2=-\dfrac14\left(\dfrac{e^{i\pi/3}+1}{e^{i\pi/3}-1}\right)^2=-\dfrac14\left(\dfrac{e^{i\pi/6}+e^{-i\pi/6}}{e^{i\pi/6}-e^{-i\pi/6}}\right)^2$$
$$r=-\dfrac14\left(\dfrac{\cos(\pi/6)}{i\sin(\pi/6)}\right)^2=\dfrac14\operatorname{cot}^2(\pi/6).\tag{5}$$

**Extension**: it happens that what has been done for $n=6$ parabola can be done for any value of $n \ge 3$ with the following immediate extension of formula (5):

$$r=\dfrac14\operatorname{cot}^2(\pi/n).\tag{5}$$

The figures represent resp. cases $n=4$ and $n=24$.

[image]

[image]

Matlab program for the figures:

> ```
>    clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal off
>    set(gcf,'color','w');
>    n=24;
>    om=exp(2*i*pi/n);
>    a=0.25*cot(pi/n)^2;
>    v=1+n/5;t=-v:0.01:v;
>    s=t.^2+i*t+a; % initial parabola
>    t=-1:0.01:1;plot(a*exp(i*pi*t),'color','r');
>    for k=1:n;
>        plot(s);
>        s=s*om;% 2*pi/n rotation of previous parabola
>    end;
> ```